# Uniqueness with a combination of numbers regardless of sequence

Tags: javascript, c#, algorithm, hash

I am working on a feature that requires me to arrive at a unique string. There are 2 attributes for every person in the data model - Company Id and Person Id. The combination of the Co and Person Id will always be unique. When 1 person initiates a conversation with another, I need to create a unique string to identify that conversation.

So, if a Person A (say Co:100, Id:100) starts a conversation with Person B (say Co:200, Id:200), the unique string should be the same as if Person B started a conversation with Person A.

I need to write this logic in JS and C#.

Comment: Somewhat unclear what you're asking.  You can easily use a Guid as a unique string (`System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")`) - Or perhaps a combination of person A, person B, and ticks since some epoch date.

Comment: Considering the identity to be internally-used only (not user-friendly per se), I can't think of any other means than GUID.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?  Do you want to have a unique conversation ID for each conversation, or do you only want one possible conversation ID when the same two people start conversations, regardless of when they start it?

Answer (score 1):

Sort the keys of the participants before creating your conversation key, this will ensure it does not matter if A starts conversation with B or the other way around.

Assuming you have a unique attribute (lower_id, higher_id) should do the trick.